# Jackson deserialization by only providing an @Id as a String

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson, deserialization

I have a simple class like this :

```
public class User {
  @Id
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
   ...
}
```

It can be obviously directly deserialized by Jackson with this JSON:

```
{
  "id": 123  // with int
  "name": "bli",
}
```

or

```
{
  "id": "123"  // with String
  "name": "bli",
}
```

However, the `@Id` annotation seems to give, by default, the possibility to deserialize the `User` class by only providing the Id. For exemple, let's say I have another class `Search` containing a `User`:

```
public class Search {
  private String title;
  private User user;
   ...
}
```

This works:

```
{
  "title": "blo",
  "user": 123 // with int
}
```

But not this:

```
{
  "title": "blo",
  "user": "123" // with String
}
```

Is there a way to allow the deserialization of a class by only providing the id as a String ?

---

Note: All my classes are bound to a Postgres database via Hibernate. Hence the @Id annotation. I deliberately ignored the other annotations here, it doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: a `number` is not a `String` why would you think that should work without a custom deserializer? that is like expecting a picture of a key to open a door instead of the actual key

Comment: Because it's already working when you try to deserialize with the full representation of the object. So obviously Jackson is tolerant about the fact it is a string depending of the situation. But not in the one that interest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so custom deserializer it will be :

```
public class UserDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<User> implements ResolvableDeserializer {

    private final JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer;

    public UserDeserializer(JsonDeserializer<?> defaultDeserializer) {
        super(User.class);
        this.defaultDeserializer = defaultDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String text = jp.getText();
        JsonToken currentToken = jp.getCurrentToken();

        if(!currentToken.equals(JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT) && !text.startsWith("{")) {
            try{
                return new User(Integer.parseInt(text));
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                throw new IOException("Unable to process '" + text + "'. Expecting an ID as an integer or a full json representation of the object.");
            }

        }

        return (User) defaultDeserializer.deserialize(jp, dc);
    }

    @Override
    public void resolve(DeserializationContext ctxt) throws JsonMappingException {
        ((ResolvableDeserializer) defaultDeserializer).resolve(ctxt);
    }
}
```

---

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() == User.class)
            return new UserDeserializer(deserializer);
        return deserializer;
    }
});
environment.getObjectMapper().registerModule(module);
```

Comment: Thanks to show how to call the default deserializer on some conditions...